# Vagrant synced folder type NFS with windows 10 error

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, windows-10

I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10, and I've solved many problems with this github issue:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/windows-10-vagrant-virtualbox-homestead

But when I call `vagrant up`, vagrant says:

```
vagrant requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

My vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/vagrant", type:"nfs"
```

When I remove type: "nfs" it's work but I need that to speed up my vm....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same trouble - and have gone back to Windows 8.1 until I know this is resolved.

However, have you checked that your Vagrant installation under W10 has the winnfsd plugin installed?

Try:
    `vagrant plugin list`
to see if it is installed.

If not, 
    `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd`
will install it.

Can't guarantee anything, but it's a useful first step.